# Java + GTK hello world

Tags: java, gtk

can anyone give a simple hello world example with java and the gtk
all I know is how to use the swing toolkit with awt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8111?page=0,1

```
public class ExampleGNOME {
 private LibGlade libglade;
 private static final String GLADE_FILE =
                               "ExampleGNOME.glade";

 public ExampleGNOME () throws IOException {
  libglade = new LibGlade(GLADE_FILE, this);
 }

 public void on_noButton_released(GtkEvent event) {
  Gtk.mainQuit();
  System.exit(1);
 }

 public void on_yesButton_released(GtkEvent event) {
  Gtk.mainQuit();
  System.exit(0);
 }

 public static void main(String args[]) {
  ExampleGNOME gui;

  Gtk.init(args);
  try {
   gui = new ExampleGNOME();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   System.err.println(e);
   System.exit(1);
  }
 Gtk.main();
 }
}
```